# UNIX Script - setting dynamic variables (indirect variable reference)

Tags: bash, variables, unix, dynamic

## How to set shell variables from an input file ?

hello,

I need to set dynamic variable from an .ini file in a shell script.

Assume the input file is *input.ini* :

```
var1=val1
var2=val2
var3=val3
```

In a script I want to set var1, var & var3 respectively to their val1, val2 & val3 to get

```
echo $var1
val1
echo $var2
val2
...
```

I've tryed :

```
file="input.ini"
while IFS== read -r f1 f2
do
   eval dynvar=$f1
   dynvar=$f2    
done <"$file"

echo $var1
echo $var2
echo $var3
```

the *echo $varx* commands give no output. How can I work it out ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
source input.ini
```

Or

```
. input.ini
```

More info

```
<source | .> filename [arguments]
    Execute commands from a file in the current shell.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't understand what you mean ... and in fact I fixed the problem after searching the web (I've never written this kind of code). See next answer

Answer (score 0):

### Solved

using :

```
file="install.ini"
while IFS== read -r f v
do
  eval "$f=$v"   
done <"$file"
```

did the trick.

Comment: Why do it manually when it can be done using a shell command like `source` as indicated in previous answer?

Comment: .. because I don't understand how it works .. I read it's used to execute a file passed as argument but I don't see the relationship with my question ...

Comment: executes commands from a file, in your case the variable assignments